# Issue in adding/removing table rows dynamically in ASP .NET using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a user control which allows user to enter multiple email recipients.
On page load, I have one table row containing name and email address textbox(with-out Remove button)

All other table rows are being added using jQuery and each row thus added has a Remove button which allow the user to delete a particular row. Below is my code:

```
<div>
<table cellspacing="5" runat="server" id="tblEmailRecipients" clientidmode="Static">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">Custom Email Recipients</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <input type="button" value="Add More" onclick="AddNewTableRow();" id="btnAdd" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="font-weight:bold">
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Email Address</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>  
    <tr>
        <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtName" ></asp:TextBox> </td>
        <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEmailAddress" ></asp:TextBox> 
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexValidatorEmailAddress" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid Email Address" ControlToValidate="txtEmailAddress" 
                    Display="Dynamic" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%--<input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="DeleteTableRow(this);" id="btnRemove" name="btnRemove" />--%>
        </td>
    </tr>        
</table>
</div>
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" onclick="btnSave_Click" 
    style="height: 26px" />
```

jQuery:

```
function DeleteTableRow(ctrl) {
    //delete control table row
    $($(ctrl).closest("tr")).remove();
}

function AddNewTableRow() {
    //Get Row clone and add as last row
    //Also, created row clone but with different control ids
    var i = $("#tblEmailRecipients tr").length;
    var newRow = $("#tblEmailRecipients tr:last").clone().find("input").each(
        function () {
            $(this).attr({
                'id': function (_, id) { return id + i },
                'name': function (_, name) { return name + i },
            });
        }).end();

    $("#tblEmailRecipients tr:last").after(newRow);
    $("#tblEmailRecipients tr:last input:text").val("");

    //Add 'Remove' button in the last column - this needs to be done only for second row, all rows after 2nd row will auto. contain Remove button as they are cloned from prev. row
    var lastCell = $("#tblEmailRecipients tr:last td:last");
    var lastCellContents = jQuery.trim($(lastCell).html());

    if (lastCellContents == '') {
        var btnRemoveName = "btnRemove" + i;
        var btnRemove = "<input type='button' value='Remove' onclick='DeleteTableRow(this);' id='" + btnRemoveName + "' name='" + btnRemoveName + "' />";
        $(btnRemove).appendTo($(lastCell));
    }    

    //Move focus to newly added row Textbox
    $("#tblEmailRecipients tr:last input:first").focus();
}
```

The issue I am facing is while handling btnSave_Click,
Even if I add 2 or more recipients(table rows), In the code behind - I see only first table row containing email recipient.

I wonder why I am not able to access other table rows that were added at run-time... they also go missing on UI after postback?

Could you please guide.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Trying giving dynamic ids to the edit boxes in each row,t you are giving all the edit boxes same id in each row.the ids should be different for each row.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Modified my question to update cloned control ids. now it's not combining textbox contents together, but I am still only able to see first email recipient(table row that is there on page load).

Comment: hmmm basically you are adding new rows using client scripting(jquery) which shows the user a new row has been added,but the server has no way of knowing that a new row was added and the server side code does not add a new row. You should add a counter or some variable to inform the server that a new row has to be added.

Comment: i recently did something like this using panels and delegates in asp.net c# in the page load,rather then using javascript.